what scale is used for solo over bIIIMaj7 when approaching II-7?

Three ways are available when approaching II-7 via bIII.
bIIIMaj7, subV/II, bIII full dim.
I blindly thought that Ionian scale is used for solo over bIIIMaj7,
but apparently Lydian is used.
Can anybody explain why?

In this particular case you can superimpose the two seventh chords and that just happens to give you a diatonic scale.

C: 
bIIIMaj7 =   Eb   G   Bb   D
II-7     = D    F   A    C

Ordered by step from C = C D Eb F G A Bb C

Nominally you get C dorian. The bIIImaj7 chord would be a borrowed chord in C major so that kind of C major/C dorian mode mixing makes sense.
This isn't necessarily the best approach to improvisation, but seemed worth mentioning, especially if the approach is to match up some "scale" of pitches to a chord or chords.
FWIW, there are a number of scales that can be describe as the superimposition of two chords. The octatonic scales come to mind, being superimpositions of two diminished seventh chords.
I don't think you need to worry too much about the Ab versus A natural, especially if the argument is about A natural's diatonic identity in C major. Firstly, the chord movement is chromatic. Secondly, it seems a pretty dogmatic attachment to diatonicity when the context is jazz. Either pitch could work if the melodic sense is solid. I'm I supposed to believe that the Ab (enharmonically G#) could not be employed as the lower auxiliary to the A, the chordal fifth of Dmin7? Of course it could!

In a major-seventh chord, the natural 11th (in this case, the note Ab in an EbM7) sounds particularly bad.  The #11th is often used instead.  This is true in any key.
user1079505's answer showing that the #11 is a member of C major is another good reason.

Because the note A is diatonic in the key of C major. It is also shared with the following II-7 chord. This is the raised 4th degree which distinguishes lydian from ionian.
